# Creating a path by using pwd

Tags: bash

Once I'm running my script, I'm creating a new file in my current location, then adding some data to this file:
`touch tracking
DATA=$(pwd/tracking)`
By the code above, I want the file to be in a general location, so I can add some data into it even if I'm not in the same location as the file's.
`echo $someRecords >> "$DATA"`.
Any idea what is wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to do by having `$(pwd/tracking)`?

Comment: `$someRecords >> "$DATA"` should be `echo $someRecords >> "$DATA"` btw. you seem to need some bash basics tutorial.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I agree. I forgot the echo in my post. Generally, I want the file to be in a general location, so I can add some data into it, even if I'm not in the same location as the file's.

Comment: ok. i think you meant `$(pwd)/tracking` instead. another way is `$(readlink -f tracking)`.

Comment: Great.Thanks! I'm new in Bash sorry:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The executable is called "pwd", not "pwd/tracking".

```
DATA="$(pwd)/tracking"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting, that in addition to the executable `pwd` you also have the variable `$PWD`. If you're so inclined, you could replace the three lines

```
touch tracking
DATA="$(pwd)/tracking"
echo $someRecords >> "$DATA"
```

with

```
DATA="${PWD}/tracking"
echo $someRecords >> "$DATA"
```

*or* if you're feeling concise, just one line

```
echo $someRecords >> "${PWD}/tracking"
```

would do the same thing